# How to convert nested array to json string in php?

Tags: php, slim, notorm

I have managed to convert the notORM object to array but now I want to convert the array into a nested json string.

```
$categoriesTable = $db->categories();

$resultant = array();

foreach($categoriesTable as $key => $object) {
    foreach($object as $property => $value) {
        $resultant[$property] = array_push($resultant, $value);
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
{"code":"1013","message":"Contacts Sync Successful","data":{"0":"1","ID":33,"1":"Food","Title":34,"2":null,"Description":35,"3":null,"ImageURL":36,"4":"2","5":"Film","6":null,"7":null,"8":"3","9":"Outing","10":null,"11":null,"12":"4","13":"Shopping","14":null,"15":null,"16":"5","17":"Party","18":null,"19":null,"20":"6","21":"Sports","22":null,"23":null,"24":"7","25":"Travel","26":null,"27":null,"28":"8","29":"Others","30":null,"31":null}}
```

For reference my categories table structure is:
ID, Title, Description, ImageURL

But I want the json output as

```
{"data":[{"table1":[{"ID":"1", "Title":"Abc"....}, {...}]}]}
```

and so on
Please help. What will be the php code for it then?

Comment: can you show what $temp contains?

Comment: Revised my post. Please check it.

Comment: Its an object and your function is fetching keys from array. so its not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did it with this approach $baseTableCollection['categories'][$looper][$property] = $value;